# Deleted recurring item showing in calendar query

Tags: 2013, calendar, recurring-events

I have a recurring list item that was deleted from the calendar and does not show in any list view. However, when I query the list, the deleted entry shows in the results.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event date was changed on the recurring event, so that it excluded the start day. I found the recurring event hiding on the next day and removed the recursion. I was then able to see the event as was intended.